# How to read a text file line by line in Phonegap using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

This is the file path:

```
 www/asset/textfile/file.txt
```

This is my script to read a text file content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.get("../textfile/file.txt", function(data){
       $("#text").html(data);
  });

)};
```

This code works fine to read content from the text file.
Now my question is "How to read these content line by line (or) character by character?" Because, when I paste the content in the HTML page, text is pasted continuously. But, there are enter keys in it.

Now, I want to read each line. When a line ends I would like to place `<br>` tag. (or)

I want to read each character. When there is an enter character I would like to place `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace line changes with `<br>` like this :

```
$.get("../textfile/file.txt", function(data){
   $("#text").html(data.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
});
```

`/\n/g` is a literal [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The `g` flag means we want to find all occurences, not just the first one.

Comment: I understand '\n' is for new line character. What is this /\n/g. They are also not in single or double quotes. Please explain me sir.

By Jona